# OpenGL C++ Minimap of current setting

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for a way to create a second view from the top of my current 3D scene. I would like to do this as easy as possible. The basic idea is that you have a subwindow that will display a top view of the setting.

I've looked into subwindows in openGL but the problem is you have to redraw everything (basically ending up with 2 scene's with different angle = not good). Also because this will be used in a 3D game called "tower box stacking" (you have to place boxes on top of each other and make a high tower) its impossible to use the subwindows way to do it (since you would get 2 scenes with different blocks/locations/actions/...)

So how can I add a "second camera" to my current scene and then position it on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've looked into subwindows in openGL but the problem is you have to redraw everything (basically ending up with 2 scene's with different angle = not good)

This is actually the one and only way to do this with OpenGL.

> So how can I add a "second camera" to my current scene and then position it on top.

OpenGL doesn't have cameras. It doesn't even have a scene. OpenGL merely *draws* very simple shapes: Points, Lines and Triangles. Above that OpenGL has no understanding of geometry or complex scenes.

Scene management is up to you and drawing multiple views of a scene is up to be implemented by you.

---

#### Update: Pseudocode

```
draw_scene:
    for o in objects:
        glPushMatrix()
        glMultMatrix(o.transform)
        o.draw()
        glPopMatrix()

render_main_view:
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glFrustum(...)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glMultMatrix(main_camera_transform)

render_secondary_view:
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glFrustum(...)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glMultMatrix(secondary_camera_transform)

scissor_viewport(x,y,w,h)
    glScissor(x,y,w,h)
    glViewport(x,y,w,h)

render:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
    scissor_viewport(main_viewport.x,main_viewport.y,main_viewport.w,main_viewport.h)
    render_main_view()

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    scissor_viewport(secondary_viewport.x,secondary_viewport.y,secondary_viewport.w,secondary_viewport.h)
    render_secondary_view()
```

Comment: Haa now I understand it! Thanks alot for this (also for other people who helped me!)

Answer (score 3):

Draw the scene once using your default settings.

Then apply a different view transformation (corresponding to your second "camera"), use `glViewport` to select a sub-rectangle of the screen and draw the scene again. (Don't forget to reset the `glViewport` to cover your entire screen again afterwards)

If you want the mini-map to have a different aspect ratio (w/h), then during the second pass you'll need to also change the perspective transformation so that everything looks OK.

Comment: Let me know if you have any further questions. If you want some code too, then I'm going to need the OpenGL version that you are using.

Comment: the problem is that the scene will change depending on physical changes in the scene, redrawing it the second time will not correspond to the first time (for example user drops box left, then right)

Comment: If you redraw the mini-screen right after redrawing the first screen, i.e. before you change the data, then both views will contain exactly the same data (just from a different look). How could it be otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this and it's a suggestion really.

So you say your game is about stacking boxes and you want an overhead view. Why not 'fake' the overhead view? Basically you create a texture that represents the minimap of your game as an orthogonal view. ONLY when a new block gets stacked, you would need to update the texture. To view it in the current position you would then have to set the appropriate texture-coordinates of the 'sub-window' or viewport.

Comment: That can work but what about a side view? Then there is alot of overhead updating the position of the box on the minimap

Comment: You didn't mention side-view. I had assumed that you only wanted to deal with top-view. If you require sub-windows for more than one view, you will need to do what @Kos has suggested.